# Почему при вводе нуля , программа продолжает работать?

Tags: c++, функции

Есть некая задача, не столь важна её суть. Не могу понять , в чём проблема, если ноль ввести , то программа должна выйти из цикла, смотрел отладчиком , а она дальше по нему ходит.

// ConsoleApplication1.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int MyFunc();
int main()
 {
MyFunc();
cout << MyFunc();
return 0;
 }
   int MyFunc() {
int k;
int value;
int Max_Element = 0;
int Value_Of_Max_Element = 0;
while (value != 0) {
    cin >> value;
    if (value > Max_Element) Max_Element = value;
    if (value = Max_Element) Value_Of_Max_Element++;
}
return Value_Of_Max_Element;
}
```

Comment: `value = Max_Element` --> `value == Max_Element`. Включите предупреждения в настройках компилятора, он бы тогда сразу ткнул вас носом в эту строчку. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat   выражение if (value = Max_Element)    идентично выражению  if ( Max_Element)  { value = Max_Element; },  Это выражение  не может являться  ошибкой. Компилятор тут может выдать только одно предупреждение, а именно  предупредить о том, что  вы забыли поставить скобки вокруг  value = Max_Element. Другое дело, что это логическая ошибка.    Я удивлен, что  столько пользователей согласны с вами

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так я и имею в виду, что это логическая ошибка.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, "Включите предупреждения в настройках компилятора, он бы тогда сразу ткнул вас носом в эту строчку"  - это же вы написали?...  Лично я благодарен всем тем, кто делает уместные замечания к моим ответам и комментариям. Это идет мне и другим на пользу.  Этот сайт предназначен именно для этого...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  если вы хотите получить  третий элемент массива  m[5]  так:  int b = m[3]; это является логической ошибкой, но компилятор не предупредит вас, так как компилятору неизвестны ваши намерения. Тем и опасны логические ошибки....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Что-то я вас не понимаю. *"Компилятор тут может выдать только одно предупреждение, а именно предупредить о том, что вы забыли поставить скобки вокруг value = Max_Element."* Я имел в виду именно это. Разве я писал что-то другое? *"Это выражение не может являться ошибкой"* А где я писал, что это ошибка?

Comment: Друзья, спасибо , конечно, что вы обсуждаете эти вещи. Но ошибка не кроется в этом. Программа не работает как нужно , даже при изменении знака равенства. Был сонный, пропустил эту ошибку. Но вопрос стоял в том, почему при вводе нуля программа продолжает просить данные, а не завершает свою работу? Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: @АлександрТокарь А по-моему как раз в этом. (Плюс, надо заменить while на do-while, как это сделали в ответе ниже.) Как вы разделяете числа, когда вводите их? Нужно пробелами или переносами строк, запятые и т.п. не подходят.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int MyFunc();
int main()
{
    int value;//это и будет ответ от функции
    value=MyFunc();

    cout << value;
    return 0;
}
int MyFunc() {
    int k;
    int value;
    int Max_Element = 0;
    int Value_Of_Max_Element = 0;
    do
    {
        cin >> value;
        if (value > Max_Element) Max_Element = value;
        if (value == Max_Element) Value_Of_Max_Element++;//знак равенства!!!
    } 
    while (value != 0);
    return Value_Of_Max_Element;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо , но эффекта , увы ,ноль. Программа после ввода нуля так-же ходит по циклу. А должна завершать свою работу.

Comment: @АлександрТокарь У меня все работает. Как вы разделяете числа, когда вводите их? Нужно пробелами или переносами строк, запятые и т.п. не подходят.

Comment: Запускаю программу. В консоли ввожу число , нажимаю enter и так далее. Не знаю, я ввожу ноль у меня переходит на следующую строку и опять ждет ввода.